# Android exception: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with this activity

Tags: android

In order to use the support action bar, my activity has to extend ActionBarActivity, and when I do that and start the activity, the application crashes with:

> Exception: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

In my styles.xml I have

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

And in my AndroidManifest.xml for the offending activity I have

```
<activity android:name="com.example.test3.SettingsActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" />
```

Comment: Do you have any other values folder? For example values-v11 or something like that?

Comment: Ah, that was it. Please write it up as an answer so I can mark it, and it can help others as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to check for other folders, that contain styles files as well, that could possibly override your styles.

Answer (score 2):

Write this line in your manifest file.

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Sample:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.vmoksha.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And Add this code in your styles.xml inside resource tag

```
      <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> 
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     </style>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Tsung Wu said:

```
<style name="Theme.Event" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

Then set the theme in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
   android:debuggable="true"
   android:name=".activity.MyApplication"
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.Event.Home">
```