# Alert Dialog crashing the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-alertdialog

This has been asked so many times, and has been answered,I have solved this problem before, but stuck this time, This is working in one place but in another activity its giving me following error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Following is the code of my registration class, the same class is written for login activity, and there its working perfectly.

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);


        if(sql_code.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
            String resultCode= command1.getString("result");
            if(resultCode.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Account Created");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Account Created Successfully.");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i= new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
```

**Manifest File**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ticketing.activities.checkout.RegistrationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">Roboto</item>
</style>
```

Everything is in place, but still its giving me this error message, Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong  here.

Comment: Can you try changing "AppCompatActivity" to "Activity" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Custom Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544405/android-custom-dialog)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: I have already seen these question, but they did not help me much thats why i posted this question.

Comment: @sunilsunny thanks, I have tried your solution but the problem is still  there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android exception: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764612/android-exception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-with-this-activity)

Comment: Check if you only have one style.xml. May be it is getting overwritten like in link given by @ste-fu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your dialog creation with the first line from this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Account Created");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Account Created Successfully.");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i= new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: That Worked Perfectly fine! Thanks :) 
It would be more awesome, if you explain why its working here.

Comment: Although `alertDialog.setButton`, is not working in this code, I have to removed that in order to make it work.

Comment: I haven't find the real problem right now but I faced the same issue few days ago, therefore I answered

Answer (score 1):

```
//instead of using it
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
//use It
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationActivity.this).create();
```

Comment: And what is the difference ?

Comment: read this so you can get  what is exactly diffrence b/w them
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: @sunilsunny Dialogs need activity context and not application context. Though usually the exception would be different in case app context was used. The question is not showing whether OP is using support lib or bare platform AlertDialog.

Comment: I am using `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

Comment: please accept the answer if its correct, so other people can also take help.

Comment: Thanks , The same thing is working is `Login Class`, but its not working here

Comment: @ Kirmani88, i have tried the same code its run perfectly,can you please send me Logcat error.

Answer (score 1):

Use this builder to create your dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog))
```

## EDIT:

Another way to fix the problem is to create a custom style:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<!-- Used for the buttons -->
<item name="colorAccent">_your_color_</item>
<!-- Used for the title and text -->
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">_your_color_</item>
<!-- Used for the background -->
<item name="android:background">_your_color_</item>
```

And then use it when building your dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `extends AppCompatActivity` to `extends Activity`.

As you can see here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/4425195

Answer (score -1):

Use `DialogFragment` for dialogs